# is there a list of all possible headers for a outlook CSV contact format?

Tags: csv, outlook, contacts

I am building a contact manager plugin for an application I have made years ago
which is up and running and can not use APIs to download contacts from Google or Microsoft
so I have to feed it outlook csv , is there a list of all possible headers? or the combinations
or the rules to make such combinations somewhere on the net?

mainly I am trying to find out, what is the rule on adding the Nth phone number, or Nth website address or Nth Address

I tried to make a contact with every imaginable input inside google contacts and export it as OULOOKS CSV and the heards are weird:

> First Name,Middle Name,Last Name,Title,Suffix,Initials,Web Page,Gender,Birthday,Anniversary,Location,Language,Internet Free Busy,Notes,E-mail Address,E-mail 2 Address,E-mail 3 Address,Primary Phone,Home Phone,Home Phone 2,Mobile Phone,Pager,Home Fax,Home Address,Home Street,Home Street 2,Home Street 3,Home Address PO Box,Home City,Home State,Home Postal Code,Home Country,Spouse,Children,Manager's Name,Assistant's Name,Referred By,Company Main Phone,Business Phone,Business Phone 2,Business Fax,Assistant's Phone,Company,Job Title,Department,Office Location,Organizational ID Number,Profession,Account,Business Address,Business Street,Business Street 2,Business Street 3,Business Address PO Box,Business City,Business State,Business Postal Code,Business Country,Other Phone,Other Fax,Other Address,Other Street,Other Street 2,Other Street 3,Other Address PO Box,Other City,Other State,Other Postal Code,Other Country,Callback,Car Phone,ISDN,Radio Phone,TTY/TDD Phone,Telex,User 1,User 2,User 3,User 4,Keywords,Mileage,Hobby,Billing Information,Directory Server,Sensitivity,Priority,Private,Categories

telex?!! ISDN?!!!

The plugin must be in Python just FYI

Comment: Just take the fields that your application needs?

Comment: To make this task even more interesting, you should be aware that field names when exporting from Outlook are localized. Just like the CSV format probably is. Example, in `da_DK` locale for Outlook, the file starts with `"Titel","Fornavn","Mellemnavn","Efternavn","Suffiks","Firma".. ` (the order also changed). So nearly impossible task to standardize across cultures.

Comment: @Fravadona i should edit my question a bit i.e I am trying to figure out what is the format for adding nth phone number or nth address, or the nth website or custom fields

Comment: @MyICQ Thank you for pointing that out, could have been a problem in the future, but now I will force English locale on all retrieves everywhere